# jwplayer streaming/seek on loading not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, video-streaming, jwplayer

I have tried everything to make my Jwplayer seek on start loading

This is my configuration with it-

```
                    <script>
                        jwplayer('player').setup({
                            file: '@Model.videopath',
                            title: '@Model.videoname',
                            width: '100%',
                            aspectratio: '16:9',
                            primary: 'flash',
                            image: '@Model.video_thumb',
                            startparam: "ec_seek",
                            seek: true,
                            autostart: true
                        });
                    </script>
```

**Seeking it-**

```
var stepTo = jwplayer("player").getPosition() + 0.01;

jwplayer("player").seek(stepTo).onComplete(function(){
    jwplayer('player').pause();
});
```

**and one from its site-**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jwplayer().onReady(function() { jwplayer().seek('10') });
</script>
```

But all failed to work. Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer, http://www.tubepinoy.net/Home/Video/58/Linkin-park-transformers-2-new-song, At here you will notice video is loaded first and starts after buffer completes itself.

Comment: Try to run this tool on your file - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are serving the file with a ranged response. You can use this method adapted from [here](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/easy-handling-of-http-range-requests-in-asp-net/):

```
 internal static void StreamVideo(string fullpath, HttpContextBase context)
    {
        long size, start, end, length, fp = 0;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fullpath))
        {

            size = reader.BaseStream.Length;
            start = 0;
            end = size - 1;
            length = size;
            // Now that we've gotten so far without errors we send the accept range header
            /* At the moment we only support single ranges.
             * Multiple ranges requires some more work to ensure it works correctly
             * and comply with the spesifications: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2
             *
             * Multirange support annouces itself with:
             * header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
             *
             * Multirange content must be sent with multipart/byteranges mediatype,
             * (mediatype = mimetype)
             * as well as a boundry header to indicate the various chunks of data.
             */
            context.Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "0-" + size);
            // header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            // multipart/byteranges
            // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.2

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"]))
            {
                long anotherStart = start;
                long anotherEnd = end;
                string[] arr_split = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_RANGE"].Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("=") });
                string range = arr_split[1];

                // Make sure the client hasn't sent us a multibyte range
                if (range.IndexOf(",") > -1)
                {
                    // (?) Shoud this be issued here, or should the first
                    // range be used? Or should the header be ignored and
                    // we output the whole content?
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");

                }

                // If the range starts with an '-' we start from the beginning
                // If not, we forward the file pointer
                // And make sure to get the end byte if spesified
                if (range.StartsWith("-"))
                {
                    // The n-number of the last bytes is requested
                    anotherStart = size - Convert.ToInt64(range.Substring(1));
                }
                else
                {
                    arr_split = range.Split(new char[] { Convert.ToChar("-") });
                    anotherStart = Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[0]);
                    long temp = 0;
                    anotherEnd = (arr_split.Length > 1 && Int64.TryParse(arr_split[1].ToString(), out temp)) ? Convert.ToInt64(arr_split[1]) : size;
                }
                /* Check the range and make sure it's treated according to the specs.
                 * http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html
                 */
                // End bytes can not be larger than $end.
                anotherEnd = (anotherEnd > end) ? end : anotherEnd;
                // Validate the requested range and return an error if it's not correct.
                if (anotherStart > anotherEnd || anotherStart > size - 1 || anotherEnd >= size)
                {
                    context.Response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fullpath);
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
                    throw new HttpException(416, "Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
                }
                start = anotherStart;
                end = anotherEnd;

                length = end - start + 1; // Calculate new content length
                fp = reader.BaseStream.Seek(start, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Response.StatusCode = 206;
            }
        }
        // Notify the client the byte range we'll be outputting
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + start + "-" + end + "/" + size);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
        // Start buffered download
        context.Response.WriteFile(fullpath, fp, length);
        context.Response.End();

    }
```